# Validation Rule to "Lock Up" UTM Fields on Opportunity when the Opportunity is created

Tags: opportunity, fields, locking

I am trying to lock the UTM fields on an opportunity when it is created. 
I would the field to not be able to be edited by anyone (including Marketo Sync User) other than a system admin after the opportunity is created

here is what I have so far:

```
AND(
$Profile.Name <>  "System Administrator",
OR(
AND(
ISCHANGED( Last_Lead_Source__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( Last_Lead_Source__c )))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED( Last_Lead_Medium__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( Last_Lead_Medium__c )))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED( Last_Lead_Term__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( Last_Lead_Term__c )))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED( Last_Lead_Campaign__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( Last_Lead_Content__c )))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED( UTM_Original_Lead_Campaign__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( UTM_Original_Lead_Campaign__c )))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED( UTM_Original_Lead_Content__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( UTM_Original_Lead_Content__c )))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED( UTM_Original_Lead_Medium__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( UTM_Original_Lead_Medium__c )))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED( UTM_Original_Lead_Source__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( UTM_Original_Lead_Source__c )))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED( UTM_Original_Lead_Term__c ),
NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE( UTM_Original_Lead_Term__c )))
)
)
)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is your issue? What behavior are you observing that you need to change?

Comment: Exactly try to be more precise with your requirement as well as the problem you are facing.

Comment: I don't want the contact fields in the validation rule to be able to be updated after an opportunity is closed on and an account. Currently the the UTM Original Fields lock after they are first populated on a Lead, the other "Last Lead" fields in theroy can update many times while still a lead.

Comment: I want to ensure that neither the "Last Lead" nor the "UTM Original" Fields can be updated by anyone other then a system admin, after a lead is converted to a contact on an account and an opportunity is closed on that account

Comment: @TheBigGuy, did you add this condition `after a lead is converted to a contact on an account and an opportunity is closed on that account`?